# Ordenar registro de una consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla la cual consigo de otra base de datos de un reloj checador.

```
idemployee            fecha
    1          '2018-09-10 8:56:00'
    2          '2018-09-10 8:58:23'
    1          '2018-09-10 14:00:23'  
    1          '2018-09-10 15:58:43' 
    2          '2018-09-10 14:04:23' 
    2          '2018-09-10 15:55:00' 
    1          '2018-09-10 18:58:00' 
    2          '2018-09-10 19:00:00'
```

Lo que quiero hacer es ordenar los registros de la siguiente manera por día en mi front uso PHP, cada id "en teoria" debe tener 4 checadas diarias, por lo cual tengo cada checada a que columna pertenece en mi front (Entrada,Salida_comedor,Regreso_comedor o salida). Tengo una tabla "horario" donde guardo la hora de ENTRADA, SALIDA_COMEDOR, REGRESO_COMEDOR Y SALIDA en la que debe checar.

```
Idemployee   Entrada    Salida_comedor   Regreso_comedor  Salia
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende. Dices que tienes una columna `fecha` y luego dices que quieres ordenar por más columnas como `Entrada, Salida...`  ¿?

Comment: al final de la consulta añade ORDER BY idemployee ASC, fecha ASC; y te saldrá en un formato medio decente. A partir de ahí ta te puedes hacer tú la tabla en el Front End que utilices

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

`SELECT Idemployee,Entrada,Salida,comedor,Regreso,Salia FROM tuTabla ORDER BY fecha, Idemployee`

Si las columnas son ficticias puedes hacer esto:

`"ValorPorDefecto" as NombreColumna`

Comment: Fíjate que el id se repite. Da la impresión de que es una tabla relacionada con varias entradas de fecha que corresponden a cosas diferentes. Lo digo porque él habla de una serie de ¿pseudo columnas?  que parecen no existir.

Comment: Así es, se repite porque es la tabla de checadas de todos los empleados y los empleados deben de checar 4 veces al día lo que requiero es sacar los registros de esa tabla y ordenarlos para mostrarlos en cuatro columnas en mi front (ENTRADA, SALIDA_COMEDOR, REGRESO_COMEDOR, SALIDA), uso php. Debo de identificar cada checada de que es, por ejemplo si x checada es ENTRADA, SALIDA_COMEDOR, REGRESO, COMEDOR Y SALIDA, no puedo tomar el primer registro del dia que sea como "entrada" ya que algunos tienen turno de 5pm a 1am.